# What to do with an Apple TV 1, in 2016?

Tags: appletv

I have a first generation Apple TV (with the 40 Gb hard drive) lying unused, in a storage box at home. I'm unsure if there's anything useful I can do with it, so was considering getting rid of it.

I understand that there are various ways that the device can be modified or jailbroken, but I don't know if these are still worthwhile or still supported in any way. After doing some research they just seem to install other media playback software.

I'm more interested in being able to stream content - ideally from services like BBC iPlayer, YouTube or Netflix. Is there any way the device can run or stream from any of these services? (I'm aware there is a YouTube client installed on the device already, but it's very old).

Apologies if this seems a strange question, but is there any point in keeping one of these, in 2016? Can anything useful or interesting be done with them now?

Comment: From an Apple perspective, you have boat anchor.  You can put it to use, but you will need a [Linux distro](http://kodi.wiki/view/Apple_TV_1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not much these days unless you want to play standard definition content or heavily mod the thing.

See here for more info on making it into a useful device for that purpose (Kodi can be configured to stream media from those services you mentioned):

http://kodi.wiki/view/Apple_TV_1

Comment: thanks for the info. I'll give that a go and post my findings here! I've no issue with content being in SD, the TV I'll be using this with only does 720p anyway so it's not going to be a problem.